# Ubuntu Lucid, cannot install ROS electric

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-lucid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the error message is like this:

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-electric-desktop-full: Depends: ros-electric-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.6-s1313715256~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-nodelet-core (= 1.6.0-s1313699788~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1313715382~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-filters (= 1.6.0-s1313699862~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.3-s1317342644~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-stage (= 1.4.0-s1313712377~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-documentation (= 1.4.2-s1314918935~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-visualization (= 1.6.4-s1316797656~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.1-s1313700748~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.1-s1315517480~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.2-s1313712024~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1313720142~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-rx (= 1.6.1-s1314995568~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.1-s1314697348~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.5-s1316581134~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.0-s1315002762~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-stage (= 1.4.0-s1313712506~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1315018274~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-common (= 1.6.0-s1313700642~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-bond-core (= 1.6.0-s1313699727~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1313726273~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-ros-comm (= 1.6.2-s1313697791~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-visualization-common (= 1.6.2-s1316578083~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1313700560~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-executive-smach (= 1.0.2-s1313706613~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-common-msgs (= 1.6.0-s1313699542~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.1-s1313700830~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-xacro (= 1.6.0-s1313699925~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-robot-model (= 1.6.1-s1315358505~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-bullet (= 2.76.3-s1313700087~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1316934842~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry (= 1.6.0-s1313700345~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-pluginlib (= 1.6.0-s1313699668~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.1-s1315009532~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1313704548~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-common (= 1.6.0-s1313699972~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-diagnostics (= 1.6.1-s1313700469~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.4-s1317331052~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

The source.list file is like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20110720.1)]/ lucid main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

the ros source file(in folder **etc/apt/source.list.d/ros-latest.list**) is like this :

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
```

Can someone tell me how to figure out what is wrong? I am quite new to ROS.
Thanks.

Shiqian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11471/ubuntu-lucid,-cannot-install-ros-electric/) by [Shiqian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1192/shiqian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-10-08**:
I am getting similar results trying to install Electric in 64 bit Natty. Thought it was just my machine configuration. Diamondback install correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your configuration looks valid to me.

Sometimes the ROS Ubuntu package repository gets into an invalid state while being updated. If so, it should work again fairly soon. Be sure to update the package descriptions when retrying:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shiqian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1192/shiqian/) on 2011-10-08**:
I think you are right. the repository were "in a invalid state". Just now I tried  it again and it works now. Great. Thanks.

**Comment by [Shiqian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1192/shiqian/) on 2011-10-08**:
I installed Ubuntu 2 days ago. so it is really a clean OS.

**Comment by [Shiqian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1192/shiqian/) on 2011-10-08**:
now, i.e., 8 hours later, I still get the same error. Is it possible that in my system some packages are missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this the same problem as here? http://answers.ros.org/question/2094/unmet-dependency-problem-while-installing-electric

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shiqian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1192/shiqian/) on 2011-10-08**:
not really. the error message are different. mine starts from missing ros_tutorial; his error msg. starts from electric-eigen; and I don't have libpcl-1.1 libeigen3-dev packages installed at all. but thanks anyway.